# Docker image jenkins/jenkins:lts-alpine DNS issue

Tags: docker, jenkins, dns, docker-swarm

I have a docker image based on jenkins/jenkins:lts-alpine. For some reason, it is not able to resolve DNS names, as shown below:

```
[root@inf-jenkins02-prd ~]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                 NAMES
716ceece2017        myjenkins/jenkins:latest   "/sbin/tini -- /us..."   12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       8080/tcp, 50000/tcp   jenkins_main.1.heaupued6g8eygrgrk6c8hlvy
[root@inf-jenkins02-prd ~]# docker exec -ti 716ceece2017 nslookup www.google.com
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

nslookup: can't resolve 'www.google.com': Try again
[root@inf-jenkins02-prd ~]#
```

However, running the following works as expected:

```
[root@inf-jenkins02-prd ~]# docker run myjenkins/jenkins:latest nslookup google.com
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

Name:      google.com
Address 1: 216.58.204.142 par21s05-in-f142.1e100.net
```

Here is the Dockerfile use to build the image:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-alpine
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false -Dhudson.DNSMultiCast.disabled=true -Dhudson.udp=-1"
USER jenkins
RUN ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_rsa
COPY security.groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/security.groovy
COPY xlocation.groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/xlocation.groovy
COPY znodes.groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/znodes.groovy
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
```

And this is the docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  main:
    container_name: jenkins-mine
    image: myjenkins/jenkins
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    volumes:
      - /home/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home/  
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Then, I'm just doing:

```
docker stack deploy -c /.../docker-compose.yml jenkins
```

Everything seems to be okay:

```
[root@inf-jenkins02-prd ~]# docker service ls
ID            NAME          MODE        REPLICAS  IMAGE
71h4jrygqp7m  jenkins_main  replicated  1/1       myjenkins/jenkins
[root@inf-jenkins02-prd ~]# docker service ps 71h4jrygqp7m
ID            NAME            IMAGE           NODE               DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE           ERROR  PORTS
heaupued6g8e  jenkins_main.1  myjenkins/jenkins  inf-jenkins02-prd  Running        Running 23 minutes ago
[root@inf-jenkins02-prd ~]#
```

but google.com can't resolve:

```
[root@inf-jenkins02-prd ~]# docker exec -ti 716ceece2017 nslookup www.google.conf
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

nslookup: can't resolve 'www.google.conf': Try again
[root@inf-jenkins02-prd ~]# docker exec -ti 716ceece2017 cat /etc/resolv.conf
search ...
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
[root@inf-jenkins02-prd ~]#
```

Any idea of what's happening here ? Many thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

If you ever see the message `nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve`, it's because `nslookup` is looking up the name of the server you're going to send the DNS query to. Since you didn't provide one, it's `null`. This is a known issue in `nslookup` (see https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/476). See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457136/nslookup-reported-cant-resolve-null-name-does-not-resolve-though-it-succ) for more details..

One thing to check is that you're looking up the right domain. 
Here, you looked up `www.google.conf`, not `www.google.com`. `www.google.conf` does not exist, so the output you got is expected.

```
# docker exec -ti 716ceece2017 nslookup www.google.conf
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

nslookup: can't resolve 'www.google.conf': Try again
```

Another thing to check is to try `nslookup` with a different DNS resolver.
For example:

```sh
docker exec -ti 716ceece2017 nslookup www.google.conf 8.8.8.8
```

Then you can see if the issue is the Internet, or the DNS server.